# Updating function level variable in a fetch request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am new to fetch and react.js and basically javascript, I am trying to create a new row in a table and just get an ID back  (second then), the problem is that temp in the then domain is changing but its not changing outside it although I defined it as function level variable

```
handleAddRow({ newRowIndex }) {
        var temp = null;

        /////////////////////////////////////// updating records in db
        fetch(`${config.serverUrl}/criteriaAPI`,
        {
            method: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
                }
        })
        .then(function(res){ return res.json(); })
        .then(function(data){  temp = data._id ;alert(temp)})
        //////////////////////////////////////
        console.log(temp);
        const newRow = {
            _id: temp,
            criteria_id: '',
            securityCriteria: '',
            description: '',
        };
       let rows = this.state.rows.slice();
        rows = update(rows, {$push: [newRow]});
    },



console.log(temp) = > null
alert(temp) = > id key : id value
```

Comment: You need to remove `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*', "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true` from the `headers` part of your fetch call. Those are response headers, so if you’ve added those to the request because you’re getting a CORS error, that’s not gonna solve the problem. If you are getting a CORS error you should use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45325697/edit to edit/update your answer to include the exact error message you’re seeing in your browser devtools console.

Comment: True I removed both lines nothing changed with respect to the CORS error I used to get it from the node.js server and it was a mistake to add them in react.js fetch request I guess the comment posted downwards is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by separating the fetch request into a single function, the problem was as mentioned above the fetch request is taking too much time, so I had another function `handleAddRow()` to wait for it using promises

```
addRow(){
        return fetch(`${config.serverUrl}/criteriaAPI`,
        {
            method: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                }
        }) 
            .then(response => {
                 return response.json()
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("fetch error" + err);
            });

    },


     handleAddRow({ newRowIndex }) {
        this.addRow()
            .then(data => {  
                let row =  this.createSingleRow(data);
                console.log(row);
                let rows = this.state.rows.slice();
                rows = update(rows, {$push: row});
                console.log(rows);
                this.setState({ rows });
            });
    },

    createSingleRow(data) {
        console.log('Entered into createRows');
        let temp = [];
        temp.push({
                _id: data._id,
                criteria_id: data.criteria_id,
                securityCriteria: data.securityCriteria,
                description: data.description
            });

        //console.log(temp);
        return temp;
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the problem is that you are calling `console.log(temp)` without waiting for the previous promises to complete, that is the execution has not yet come to the point where you assign value to temp variable. So the value of the temp variable does change - but it happens some time after `console.log(temp)` gets executed.

If you want to use temp variable and it is filled in the asynchronous manner - you must access it in the corresponding `then` handlers.

Comment: I though about this but the problem is that I cannot access `this.state.rows` inside the `.then` domain because they are defined in the react initial state

Comment: do you think there is a way to implement a call back function inside the then?

Comment: Keeping context of `this` is a known "issue", there are multiple ways to solve it, check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Comment: Thank you for the link, this is the new code `.then(function(data){  
            
            const newRow = {
                _id: data._id,
                criteria_id: '',
                securityCriteria: '',
                description: '',
            };
            console.log(newRow);
            let rows = self.temp;
            rows = update(rows, {$merge: [newRow]});
            console.log(rows);
            self.setState({ rows });
        }) ` the problem now is that I want the class context to call setState from the class